# MySQL select SUM with conditional to change the sign of the column being summed

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table that stores transactions between companies with each row structured like:

```
(int) buyerId | (int) sellerId | (float) transactionAmount
```

I want to take a particular company ID and find out which company they have the most one-sided net transaction history with.  For example, company A has an ID of 100.  I want to find out which company has the highest net value of SALES - PURCHASES.  If the table data is as follows:

```
buyerID     sellerId    transactionAmount
100         200         10.00
200         100         5.00
100         300         1.00
```

Company 100 has purchased $10.00 of goods from company 200, and company 200 has purchased $5.00 of goods from company 100 for a total net transaction value of $5.00.  Company 100 also has a net transaction value of 1.00 with company 300 but that is less than $5.00 and I am interested in the maximum here.

Is there a MySQL query I can use to find this $5.00 sum  ($10.00 + (-$5.00)) where the value in the transactionAmount field can be changed to positive/negative depending on which company is the buyer and which company is the seller?  Or do I need to fetch all relevant rows and calculate this maximum in code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this simpler solution:

This gets the company that has the highest net transactional value with this particular company (100):

```
SELECT 
    IF(buyerID = 100, sellerID, buyerID) AS other_company,
    SUM(IF(buyerID = 100, transactionAmount, transactionAmount * -1)) AS netSum
FROM transactions
WHERE 100 IN (buyerID, sellerID)
GROUP BY other_company
ORDER BY netSum DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db727/7/0)

By the way, I like your username =)

Comment: Thanks this is excellent!  Also, I didn't mention it but I am also interested in the total sum for each company.  For any future readers of this question, the query above can be slightly modified as follows to achieve that:  

`SELECT IF(buyerID = 100, sellerID, buyerID) AS other_company,  
SUM(IF(buyerID = 100, transactionAmount, transactionAmount * -1)) AS netSum   
FROM transactions  
WHERE 100 IN (buyerID, sellerID)  
GROUP BY other_company  
ORDER BY netSum DESC  
LIMIT 1`

Comment: @stackunderflow, great! Glad to hear it works for you. I've just updated my answer to include the `SUM` amount in the selection.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine all records where company in question is seller with ones where it is a buyer, but toggle a sign of transactionAmount, all that is left to do is to sum and order results by amount. Here is [TEST @ SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/148c5/6).

```
select partner, 
       sum(Amount) Amount
from
(
  select sellerid Partner, 
         sum(transactionAmount) Amount
    from Table1
   where buyerid = 100
   group by sellerid
  union all
  select buyerid, 
         -sum(transactionAmount) Amount
    from Table1
   where sellerid = 100
   group by buyerid
) t
group by partner
order by Amount desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have selected the simpler query submitted by Zane Bien as the best answer, but this one is also correct.